# Unable to use 'fs' module of Nodejs in webos

Tags: node.js, webos, lg

I want to simply write to a file but it does not work properly.I returns me null in error inspite of that it does not write anything into file. I also referred 
https://www.webosose.org/docs/guides/development/js-services/using-node-js-modules/ this url. But it does not work properly.

```
var Service = require('webos-service');
    var service = new Service("com.xynage.app.node.service");
    var fs = require('fs');
    service.register("base64ToImgStore", function(message) {
         var base64Str = message.payload.base64ToImgStore;
         var file = './demo.txt';
         fs.writeFile(file,'hy I am Mitesh!',encoding="utf8",function(err){
           message.respond({
              data:err
           });
         });


     });
```

Comment: `encoding="utf8"` is not the correct syntax.  You can just pass `"utf8"` or `{encoding: "utf8"}` as in `fs.writeFile(file, 'hy I am Mitesh!', "utf8", function(err) {...});` or . `fs.writeFile(file, 'hy I am Mitesh!', {encoding: "utf8"}, function(err) {...});`. You should also be logging the `err` in the callback so if you get an error you know what it is.

Comment: I also tried {encoding: "utf8"} but still I does not work. When I try to print err variable it gives me following output:-  {"data": null, "returnValue":true} So I think its success but still not working. Please help me